# How to remove item in recyclerview in android

Tags: android

i am doing simple cart application. which will show cart details in recycler view.
Here i am going to decrease the quantity value upto 1.The item going to be remove from item adapter.it will be working fine.But when i was going to decrease the second item quantity value,it will remove without checking the condition. My condition is if the quantity is below 1 the item going to remove.

ItemAdapter.java

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<ItemData> itemDataList;
    int quantity,t_amount;
    totalAmount totalAmount;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemData> itemDataList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.itemDataList = itemDataList;
        totalAmount = (ItemAdapter.totalAmount) context;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_details,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int pos) {
        ItemData itemData = itemDataList.get(pos);
        holder.txtPrice.setText(itemData.getPrice());
        holder.txtDesc.setText(itemData.getDescription());
        holder.txtCartCount.setText(itemData.getCartCount());
        holder.btnCartDec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(quantity <= 1){
                    itemDataList.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition(),itemDataList.size());
                }else {
                    quantity = Integer.parseInt(itemDataList.get(pos).getCartCount());
                    quantity = quantity-1;
                    itemDataList.get(pos).setCartCount(String.valueOf(quantity));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    holder.txtCartCount.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));
                }

            }
        });
        holder.btnCartInc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(itemDataList.get(pos).getCartCount());
                quantity = quantity+1;
                itemDataList.get(pos).setCartCount(String.valueOf(quantity));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                holder.txtCartCount.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemDataList.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtPrice, txtDesc, txtCartCount, btnCartDec, btnCartInc;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemView_price);
            txtDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemView_desc);
            txtCartCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemView_Count);
            btnCartDec = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemViewDec);
            btnCartInc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemViewInc);
        }
    }
    public interface totalAmount{
        void t_amount(int amount);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just need knows the item position and adds below code in adapter

```
mDataset.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataSet.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

You must get the `quantity` related to the position before your if condition. In your case the `quantity` value is the previous value, that's why the `if` condition is true.

```java
holder.btnCartDec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // You must get the quantity of the currently clicked item here
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(itemDataList.get(pos).getCartCount());
                if(quantity <= 1){
                    itemDataList.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition(),itemDataList.size());
                }else {
                    quantity = Integer.parseInt(itemDataList.get(pos).getCartCount());
                    quantity = quantity-1;
                    itemDataList.get(pos).setCartCount(String.valueOf(quantity));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    holder.txtCartCount.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks @sanoj, My problem was solved.Your solution is working.But I want to do one more thing. how to calculate price with quantity.each item has a different price.how to get sum of all item value.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove your item from model at specific position.After that notify Adapter that some changes has been done in list using `notifyDataSetChanged();`.

```
list.remove(getAdapterPosition())
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove from list of that position and notify adater ,it will remove.

replace this code

```
itemDataList.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRangeChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition(),itemDataList.size());
```

to this

```
itemDataList.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());notifyDataSetChanged();
```

it will work